# How string can be removed recurring characters and only stay unique chars in Php?

Tags: php, string, char, unique, repeat

How string can be removed recurring characters and only stay unique chars in  Php?
 For example: this is the string xsxssssdddxxxs I need the result should be xsd

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this,

```
$str = 'aassdd';
echo implode('',array_unique(str_split($str, 1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$str = "my string that contains multiple same charactersasldjasj";
echo implode('',array_unique(str_split($str, 1)));
```